# Remove list content Type Association from document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

How to remove list Content Type Association from Document Library.I have 14 content types in my SP 2013 portal. I want to know how to achieve this using PowerShell?

```
   $msite= Get-SPSite $siteurll
   $AllWebsCollection = $msite.AllWebs
   foreach($singlweb  in $AllWebsCollection)
   {
      $objWeb =  Get-SPWeb  $singlweb.Url
      foreach($singleDocLib in $DocLibss)
      {
          $ContentTypeName= "Memo"
          $singCTYpe=    $singleDocLib.ContentTypes[$ContentTypeName]
          # how to delete the list content type association ?
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$singleDocLib.ContentTypes.Delete($singCType.Id)
$singleDocLib.Update()
```

Comment: am getting the below  error:                                                                           Cannot convert argument "id", with value: "", for "Delete" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId": "Cannot convert null to type 
"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId"."
At line:19 char:6
+      $singleDocLibKG.ContentTypes.Delete($singCType.Id)
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Comment: It seems `$singCTYpe` is null. Make sure you are getting `$singCTYpe` properly.

Comment: Amal,                                                                                                             my mistake. I was accessing the wrong object.Now its corrected.

Comment: I added the $myct.ReadOnly=$false $myct.Update() also. then its worked